# Case Insensitive Grep?

Tags: perl, grep

I am using this grep statement in PERL to find non-duplicated names.  Can anyone tell me how to make it case-insensitive?  I know I need to use an 'i', but I'm not sure where it goes.  Thanks!

```
@nondup = grep {$marked{$_}++; $marked{$_} = 1;} @names
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either [`fc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) ([Perl 5.16](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/pod/perl5160delta.pod#New_function_fc_and_corresponding_escape_sequence_%5CF_for_Unicode_foldcase) or newer) or [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'fc';

my @names = qw(apple Apple foo bar baz BaZ bar);

my %seen;
my @unique = grep {! $seen{fc $_}++} @names;

print "@unique";
```

Outputs:

```
apple foo bar baz
```

Comment: You can use `fc` in older perl with the `Unicode::CaseFold` module :)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding @Miller.  I think we have a really old version of PERL on our server; we really don't use it much anymore.  I did finally get the code to work by using lc in this way.
    grep {$marked{lc $_}++; $marked{lc $_} = 1;}

Would you happen to know how to get a count of the elements in the new non-duplicated array?  I've tried a few things ($#nondup and assigning the array values to a variable), but neither worked.  I can however print out the names and see that it is correct.

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking at this and needs help, I ended up having to write the array to a new temporary file, count the rows, and return the result.  I guess something strange was happening because I was in an if statement.  I'm sure there is an easier way, but this worked for me and gave me the count I need of non-duplicated names.  Thanks so much to all of who helped me.